# Send string with QueryString in Datalist Control in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I use a Datalist Control for showing the data in my WebSite. I use a HyperLink in the Datalist Control for passing value to other page. i want to pass my ID to other page by string query..

My Code

```
<asp:DataList ID="xlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" Width="650" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <h2 align="center"></h2>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

    <div class="svc-box">
    <img src="ProjectsImages/<%#Eval("Pimg")%>" width="200" height="200" />
    <span><%#Eval("Pname")%></span>
    <a href="Project1.aspx?A="<%#Eval("PID") %>"">Details</a>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes around the EVAL in your link instead of double

For example...

```
<a href="Project1.aspx?A='<%#Eval("PID") %>'">Details</a>
```